# How can I insert a null value into Sql Server date column using asp.net and command parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
SqlDateTime sqldatenull = SqlDateTime.Null; 
sSql = "INSERT INTO mydb.dbo.myTable(FromPeriod) Values (@FromPeriod)";

if (sFromPeriod.Length == 0) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromPeriod", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters["@FromPeriod"].Value = sqldatenull;
} else {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromPeriod", sTempFromPeriod);
}

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

sFromPeriod is a date and when it's length is zero, I receive error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.  When sFromPeriod has a value, the code works fine.  I have also used DBNull.Value in place of sqldatenull and received the same error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does your column accept `null` values at all?

Comment: Are you aware that `sFromPeriod` and `sTempFromPeriod` is not the same thing?

Comment: Look into nullable data type ( SqlDateTime?)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `DBNull.Value` instead of `SqlDateTime.Null`.

For example:

```
cmd.Parameters["@FromPeriod"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```